# Show 3 top results according to date using sql

Tags: php, sql, database, select

I have a website , and I created a book library in it.

The table is: `book`

It contain: `book_id` , `book_title` , `book_cat` , `book_img` , `book_content` , `active` , `book_date` , `visits` , `book_sender` )

The 'book_sender' is the ID of the sender because any logged in user can add books ,
I wanted to make a gift each week to the best sender (who sent alot of books)
so I wanted to show top 3 sender's **of the week** in a PHP file to make challenge between the top3.

```
Champ
----------
book_id
book_title
book_cat
book_img
book_content
active
book_date
visits
book_sender
```

Comment: top3 in a week or the whole period?

Comment: top 3 in a week (Last 7 days)
Thank you

Comment: Are you just looking for the SQL query, or all the attendant PHP code as well?

Comment: both of them if you can :)

Comment: Does this table actually track the "sends" or is there another related table that tracks that? It seems odd that you would not have these normalized.

Comment: the table 'book' track the sends , and 'book_sender'=userID of the sender :) you should be a user to send a book .

Comment: what Mike means is the following: asumed, a title is sent in by three different users, that will end in three entries, three different book ids with the same title/author/ etc. Hard to do the opposite query: "what are the titles send in most often ..." - database layout and design is crucial for performance.

Comment: books need approval ! so we delete diplicated books , and what i wanted is : show the top3 of book_sender , means Count how many time book_sender repeated and show top 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippet (replace db_name, db_user, and db_password with appropriate values):

```
<?php
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=UTF8', 'db_user', 'db_password');
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
   $stm = $db->prepare( "
      SELECT book_sender `Sender ID`, COUNT(*) `Books Sent`
      FROM Champ
      WHERE book_date > DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL -7 DAY )
      GROUP BY book_sender
      LIMIT 0, 3" );
    $stm->execute();
    while( $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
       $result[] = $row;
    }

    // Step through $result and print out

?>
```

Also assuming you're using MySQL and PDO.

Comment: i tried it ! but it dont work ! i tried lot of ways ! like include config.php ...
" Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in .... "

Comment: You must not have had the connection function I was assuming.  Snippet amended to include a generic connection string and instantiating a PDO DB object.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAY, -7 ) GROUP BY book_sender LIMIT 0, 3' at line 3' in **URL** !

Comment: Oopsie, date_add() parameters were for the wrong platform.  Edited, try again.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sysdate() in **URL**

Comment: Did the simple way, so no parameter binding is needed.

Comment: should i remove this parameter ? "sysdate()" ?

Comment: Yes.  Code amended.  The entire `$stm->bindParam` statement should now, and `:today` in the query should be replaced with the mysql function `now()`

Comment: I used:
**
<?php
**  AS Your Code because its too long as a comment :) **
   $stm = $db->prepare( "
     
 SELECT book_sender `book_sender`, COUNT(*) `book_sender`
      FROM book
      WHERE book_date > DATE_ADD( now(), INTERVAL -7 DAY )
      GROUP BY book_sender
      LIMIT 0, 3" );
    $stm->execute();
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
       $result[] = $row;
    }
?> **
and the result is: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in **url**

Comment: i changed 'stmt' to 'stm' and the page is blank now !! i think i need to print the result now ? right !?

Comment: Correct.  Stepping through and displaying an associate array is probably another question, likely one that has already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

the sql query goes like this:

```
select book_sender, count(book_id) as num_books 
from champ 
where DATEDIFF(sysdate(), book_date) <= 7 
group by book_sender
limit 0, 3;
```

Comment: MySQL a répondu:
#1305 - FUNCTION databaseName.date_diff does not exist

Comment: this one works good ,
(MySQL n'a retourné aucun enregistrement. (traitement: 0.0035 sec.))
how to print the result in a php file ?